# How to activate a deactivated num_lock?

Tags: ubuntu, xmodmap, numlock

I use the following code to deactivate the num lock key.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = """
```

How can I activate the num lock key again? I think I have to use something like:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = ?
```

but I do not know what use instead of ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the key back to `Num_Lock`:

`xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = Num_Lock"`